# Migrating an Access 2002 Application to Access 2019 or SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, vba, database, ms-access

I have a series of Access 2002 "Front-end/Back-end" applications all related to each other. For example, application A has linked tables with application B and vice versa.

The applications are at a stage where daily compaction and repair is required due to the volume and high level of corruption. Moreover, to be able to make the applications work properly, I must make the changes in a virtual environment with Access 2002. I also need to reinstall "Access runtime 2010 - 32bits" and copy the Access files (.mde) on every workstation (Windows 10) every time I am making a change in the applications.

@Gustav This is a temporary option (6 months to 18 months) because the customer would like to go to a complete solution with SQL database. The studied solution is configurable and already has a SQL database schema.

I have already done the test to transfer forms, tables, queries and modules to Access 365 but I have errors in the VBA code. All business rules are coded in the VBA code. I also did the transfer of the tables to SQL Server 2017 but I'm afraid I will have to change a lot of VBA code because of the disuse of the DAO engine in the Access 365 front-end.

In fact, to be clearer, I wonder about the need to change the front end to Access knowing that it is a temporary solution.

Maybe, I should keep the software under respirator by eliminating data history in large tables. The time the client takes their decision. Find the "sweet spot" that would allow me to erase and continue to maintain it without having to worry about corruptions because I have a hard time seeing a substantial gain in the migration to the Access 365 front-end. What do you think?

I have already proposed to migrate applications and tables in the new version of to Access 2019 and even moving on SQL Server. However, for now, I must put the application on the respirator and continue the daily compaction until a decision is made.

I would like to know if there is a gain to migrate from Access 2002 to the Access 2019 version knowing the total limit of 2 GB Access. What are the major constraints he would have to migrate to a SQL database knowing that the VBA application and code uses the DAO method?

@Albert D. Kallal
I really like your answer. I should come to a decision soon.
However, I have 2 additional questions. Perhaps, could you guide me on the subject.

There are two things that have recently came to haunt the tranquility that reigned over these applications.

1- For a unknown reason, one of the applications that was part of the swarm of Access applications was blocked for some time with these errors 'Runtime 3027: Cannot update: Database or object is read only'. The problem is that some users have ignored this error and continue their tasks which caused a data shift. 
I had to go back with backup copy because some tables were not updated.

Looking more closely at the error in the VBA code I noticed that it all came from the DAO Recordset.Edit method containing queries with multiples joins.

I managed to work around this problem by modifying the Edit method with DoCmd.RunSQL and by changing the query from a Select to an Update query.
However, the whole method worked perfectly well before.
Can you explain to me the cause of this error?

2- The original developer did not necessarily use best practices for the design of the application (no autonumber, some tables without primary key, no foreign keys) so I'm afraid that a new design will need to be done if I migrate to a SQL Server database. Or maybe to save time, as this solution is going to disappear in 18 months, I should only replicate the bad practices in SQL Server and pray that it does not cause any more glitches. What would be your professional approach?

Thank you

Comment: DAO works fine in Access 2019/365. It is just a different reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

To update your mde or accDE front end? That is a simple copy to each workstation. You don’t need to re-install the runtime each time. There is no “special” connection between one particular application (mde/accde) that you deploy to each workstation.

In other words:

If you writing software in VB6, then you need to install the VB6 run time (but only one time). After that you can simply copy + deploy your application to each workstation.

If you writing software in say .net then again, you have to ensure the correct .net framework is installed on each computer. Once done, then again you can update your software by a simple copy to each workstation.

And the same goes for using the access run time. Once installed, then you can simply copy any mde/accDE to that workstation, double click on it and it will run. So  the run time is not connected to any particular database you copy to the workstation. Once you have  the runtime installed, then you can rather easy cook up some automatic update code for the front end to "check" some version number, and then copy down the new updated front end. There are quite a few ways to do this - even a simple batch file can often suffice here.

So in near all cases these days, you will have to do  “one time” install of the required run-time and support libraries. This is the case for .net, older VB6 programs, or Access.

As for migration of the access table data to SQL server?

You should be able to simply migrate the table data to SQL server. Now link the application tables from the older access back end to SQL server.

At this point, 99% of your VBA and even DAO recordset code should work just fine.

There is no need (or even a good reason) to dump using DAO code you have – it should work as before with VERY few modifications.

About the only change is for code that does this:

```
Dim strSQL     As String
Dim rst        As DAO.Recordset

strSQL = "select * from tblCustomers where City = 'Edmonton'"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

' above for SQL server becomes:

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

And you can even migrate the tables with indexes, and table relationships intact by  using the Sql Server Migration Assistant for Access (SSMA). You can find this fantastic tool here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255

So, about 99% of existing forms  and VBA code will work as before after you migrate the data to SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

There may be none. Open the database in Access 2019/365 and save it in the 2007 (accdb) format, and check it out.

As for the distribution, you can make this fully automatic using a script and a shortcut. It is explained in full in my article:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html)

If you don't have an account, browse to the link: Read the full article.

Push hard to get a confirmation on the move of *all* the shared tables to an SQL Server backend.